# Error: "Declaration expected but identifier 'SysUtils' found"

Tags: delphi-7

I am trying to use multiple identifiers in Delphi 7 receiving error

```pascal
uses
   Math;
   SysUtils;
```

I am however receiving the error above.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You could have answered this yourself by reading the documentation, or indeed any other unit that compiled. It's going to be important to learn how to tackle basic problems like this yourself rather than giving up the instant you see a compiler error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
uses
      Math,
      SysUtils;
```

Semicolon (`;`) is a end of statement character, comma (`,`) separates items.